# How to transform an R data frame with multiple classes into one class?

Tags: r, dataframe, class

When I call the `dput()` function on my `df` data frame I am presented with multiple classes.

```
df %>% dput()
#> ...
#> class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
#> ...
```

How do I transform this data frame into a single class? I would get something like this I imagine:

```
df %>% dput()
#> ...
#> class = "data.frame"
#> ...
```

I'm having a [separate issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61418383/rs-padr-package-claiming-the-datetime-variable-does-not-vary-when-it-does-var) and I suspect this (multiple classes in a date frame) may be a contributing factor.

Comment: what does `str(df)` show?

Comment: @developer when I `str(df)` I get `tibble [5,856 x 10] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)` followed by the column types which include "chr', "Date", and "logi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the class like that:

```r
class(df) <- "data.frame"
```

If you want to change the class in a `pipe`, from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58539609/r-can-i-update-the-class-of-a-an-object-in-a-magrittr-pipe), use `df %>% "class<-"("foo")`

Example:

```r
data.table::data.table(x = rnorm(10)) %>% "class<-"("foo")
$`x`
 [1] -1.7728669 -0.3643645  0.4410907  0.3494225 -0.3214129  0.8595643  0.8794649  0.3891513
 [9] -2.2456579 -0.6045959

attr(,"row.names")
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
attr(,"class")
[1] "foo"
```

Comment: can you also add the way to write that into a pipe? is it something like `df %>% class("data.frame")` which doesn't quite seem to work.